# A set of objects that satisfy $a^2 = \alpha x$ and commute

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

Is there any set of mathematical objects that satisfies all of the following:

1) For each object $a$ in the set, $a^2$ is some multiples of $x$.

2) $ab$ is never multiples of $x$ where $a$ and $b$ are any different two objects in the set.

3) all objects commute - $ab = ba$ and $a+b = b+a$.

Does such set exists for all cardinality?

Edit: to specify, let objects be matrices.

Comment: What kind of structure? What is $x$? What is the motivation?

Comment: any structure - $x$ is a given one.

Comment: specified: matrices.

Comment: When you say "multiples of x", do you just mean scalar multiples ($2x, pi\cdot x$, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a set $Y$ of the required cardinality, $x$ an element not in $Y$, and $S$ the algebra of some field $K$ with generators $\{x\}\cup Y$ and relations $a^2=x$ and $ab=ba$ for all $a,b\in S$.

Seriously, if you don't want to specify what your question is about, you can only expect trivial answers like this.

Comment: Did you mean to write "with generators $\{x\}\cup Y$"?

Comment: @GregorBruns: yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be your set with the proposed structures, and $x$ is the distinguished element.  I can only assume that you require $x \in S$, and that $S$ is closed under the usual operations of $+$ and $\times$, since otherwise, property (1) makes little sense.

Your property (2) implies that your set $S$ can only consist of $\{x\}$ (a singleton set).  Indeed, if $a \neq x$, then $a\cdot x$ should not be a multiple of $x$, but certainly $ax$ is a multiple of $x$.  Thus $a=x$.

Thus, only for cardinality = $1$ will $S$ exist.